# PySide6 plugin erorr (xcb)

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, pyside, pyside6

I install Linux Mint and rise erorr when start application with PySide6:
`qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: vnc, minimalegl, vkkhrdisplay, wayland, xcb, wayland-egl, eglfs, offscreen, minimal, linuxfb.`

If i use PyQt5 i don't have error. But i need PySide6

I tired to install "xcb" - sudo apt install xcb
I tired: export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/path/to/plugins

Comment: How did you install PySide? If it was already installed, did you try to upgrade it using the package manager? Also, what is the reason of its requirement against PyQt?

Comment: I use: pip install pyside6 @musicamante

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem!

I use: apt install libxcb-cursor0

Source: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-2306